# RSyslog Client With OpenSSL 1.0.2 Cipher Suites Configuration

Tags: openssl, tls1.2, rsyslog

Need help in configuring rsyslog client with OpenSSL driver to restrict the cipher suites used for TLS communication.

**Environment:**

Using a Photon 3.x OS. Below are the details of rsyslog and openssl versions.

```
[/]# rpm -qa | grep rsyslog
rsyslog-8.2106.0-1.ph3.x86_64

[/]# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2za-fips  24 Aug 2021
```

**Configuration:**

Below is the rsyslog configuration under /etc/rsyslog.d folder for TLS client.

```
global(
# make ossl driver the default
DefaultNetstreamDriver="ossl"
# certificate files
DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/path/to/syslogCACert.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/path/to/syslogClientCert.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/path/to/syslogClientKey.pem"
)

if $programname == ["program-1", "program-2"] then {
  action(type="omfwd"
    protocol="tcp"
    StreamDriver="ossl"
    StreamDriverAuthMode="x509/name"
    StreamDriverMode="1"
    StreamDriverPermittedPeers="server.ca.com"
    target="192.168.20.21"
    port="6515"
    gnutlsPriorityString="Protocol=TLSv1.2
     Curves=P-384
     ClientSignatureAlgorithms=RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384
     SignatureAlgorithms=RSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384
     CipherString=<How to configure>"
  )
}
```

With above configuration, the protocol, curves and signature algorithms are being restricted as expected. Refer the wireshark trace with restricted curves and signature algorithms - https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmiFs.png

I'm trying to restrict the cipher suite with only below values

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
```

For the `CipherString`  key in above rsyslog config file, I tried various values listed in below reference document#4 and document#5. Somehow I can not get it to work as expected. In the wireshark I can always observe 53 cipher suites presented by the rsyslog to the remote TLS server.

Following are some of the options that I tried, but nothing seems to be working.

```
CipherString=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
CipherString=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
CipherString='ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'
CipherString=SHA384  # To restrict ciphers with SHA384 only
CipherString='SHA384' # Same as above, but with quotes
CipherString=kECDHE+aRSA+AESGCM+SHA384 # To match the first cipher in above list
CipherString=kECDHE:aRSA:AESGCM:SHA384 # To match the first cipher in above list
CipherString=AESGCM 
CipherString=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2 # Just to see the if it makes any difference
```

Kindly suggest the right way to configure CipherString.

**References:**

1. Rsyslog TLS client example: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls_cert_client.html
2. Rsyslog Forwarding Output module documentation: https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfwd.html
3. OpenSSL SSL_CONF_CMD documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html
4. OpenSSL CipherString documentation: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html
5. OpenSSL wiki about FIPS mode TLS: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_mode_and_TLS

---

Update: Sought guidance from rsyslog team as well - https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/4686

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try putting CipherString= _before_ at least one of the working items and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, thanks for looking into this. I moved `CipherString=` two lines above (i.e., to the next line of `Curves=`) and tested with following values: `'TLSv1.2+FIPS:kRSA+FIPS:!eNULL:!aNULL'` and `TLSv1.2+FIPS:kRSA+FIPS:!eNULL:!aNULL` (value picked from https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/FIPS_mode_and_TLS#TLS_1.2). But did not make any difference, still the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed as part of Rsyslog version v8.2110 - https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/pull/4692